# urllib.request.urlopen is behaving strange. Not returning the data the next day. Why?

Tags: python, json, urllib

I am trying to read Twitter feeds using the URL. Yesterday I was able to pull some 80K tweets using the code and due to some updates on my machine, my Mac terminal stopped responding before the python code completed.

Today the same code is not returning any json data. It is throwing me empty results. While if I type the same URL in browser I am able to get a json file with full of data.

Here is my code: 
**Method 1:**

```
try:
    urllib.request.urlcleanup()
    response = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
    print('URL to  used: ', url)
    testURL = response.geturl()
    print('URL you used: ', testURL)
    jsonResponse = response.read()
    jsonResponse = urllib.request.urlopen(url).read()
```

This printed:

```
URL to  used:  https://twitter.com/i/search/timeline?f=tweets&q=%20since%3A2017-08-14%20until%3A2017-08-15%20USA&src=typd&max_position=
URL you used:  https://twitter.com/i/search/timeline?f=tweets&q=%20since%3A2017-08-14%20until%3A2017-08-15%20USA&src=typd&max_position=
json:  {'items_html': '\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n \n', 'focused_refresh_interval': 30000, 'has_more_items': False, 'min_position': 'TWEET--', 'new_latent_count': 0}
```

****Method 2:****

```
try:
    request = urllib.request.Request(url, headers=headers)
except:
    print("Thats the problem here:")

try:
    response = urllib.request.urlopen(request)
except:
    print("Exception while fetching response")

testURL = response.geturl()
print('URL you used: ', testURL)

try:
    jsonResponse = response.read()
except:
    print("Exception while reading response")
```

Same results in both the cases.

Kindly help.

Comment: I get the same response as you do.

Comment: It is strange right .. sometimes I get it and sometimes not

Comment: Well, I do not get in the browser a reasonable response either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on my testing this behavior has nothing to do with `urllib`.  The same thing happens with the `requests` library for example.

It appears Twitter detects automated scraping via repeated hits against the search URL, based on your IP address and user agent  (UA) string.  At some point, subsequent hits return empty results.  This seems to happen after a day or so, probably as a result of delayed analysis on Twitter's part.

If you change the UA string in the search URL request header, you should once again receive valid results in the response.  Twitter will probably block you again after a while, so you'll need to change your UA string frequently.

I assume Twitter expires these blocks after some timeout, but I don't know how long that will take.

By way of reference, the [twitter-past-crawler project](https://github.com/keitakurita/twitter-past-crawler/blob/master/src/twitterpastcrawler/crawler.py#L276-L277) demonstrates using a semi-random UA string taken from a file containing multiple UA strings.

Also, the [Twitter-Search-API-Python](https://github.com/tomkdickinson/Twitter-Search-API-Python) project uses a hardcoded UA string, which stopped working a day or so after my first test.  Changing the string in the code (adding random characters) resulted in a resumption of prior functionality.

Comment: Yes, absolutely I agree with your response. I tested this too. When I changed to a different IP address then things started working well.

Comment: There are 3 types of errors  1. no min_position in the response 2. there is no json in the timeline search response 2. response is empty , it is better to test and analysis the reason being respectively .